# MySQL - How to create a trigger to prevent creating another table after 20 book reviews

Tags: mysql

I need help creating a trigger for this SQL problem:

- BookAuthor(book, year, author, earnings)
- BookReference(book, year, referencedBook, referencedYear, times)
- BookReview(book, year, reviewer, score)
- BookPublish(book, year, publisher, price, num)

No reviewer may review more than 20 books published in the same year

Comment: The ordering of your list (d, a, b, c) could do with some improvement for clarity.

Comment: Edited, thanks - @DavidMetcalfe